# Sum values of a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sum, math

```
<% @pid = item.producto_id %>
<br/>

Producto: <%= Producto.find_by_id(@pid) %><br/>
Costo de Compra: <%= @costo_de_compra = Producto.find(:all, :conditions => "id = '#{@pid}'").*.costo_de_compra %><br/>
Precio de venta: <%= @precio_de_venta = item.precio_de_venta %><br/>
Utilidad de este producto: <%= @precio_de_venta - @costo_de_compra %><br/><br/>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller i have=

```
@ventas_ocurridas_en_este_periodo = Venta.find(:all, :conditions => ['created_at >= ? and created_at <= ?', Date.today.beginning_of_month, Date.tomorrow])
```

As i am looping and getting values from the items that aren't available originally how can i sum all the values that come off from this loop into a concentred total?

also i can't make the operation of @precio_de_venta - @costo_de_compra... something about arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see several issues with your code. First, you should avoid dealing with id columns directly. After all, that's why you put all those `belongs_to` and `has_many` relations into your models. For example, what you call item is a venta or sell object, and it `belongs_to` Product as it includes a column named `product_id`. Therefore, you can use

```
item.product
```

instead of

```
@pid = item.producto_id
Product.find_by_id(@pid)
```

not to mention that `find_by_id` can be replaced by just a regular `find`.

For adding and finding totals, I recommend you to look into the [`inject`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) ruby function.

`@costo_de_compra` is an array as it comes from a `find(:all)` instead of a `find(:first)`. I am not sure about what your `.*.` do.